# How to spawn card sprite

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a card sprite that I would like to spawn at a specific transform position but can't get anything to appear

My Code -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CardSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform spawnPoints;
    private int spawnIndex = 0;
    public Sprite cardsToSpawn;

    void Start()
    {
        Spawncard();
    }

    public void Spawncard()
    {
        Instantiate(cardsToSpawn, spawnPoints.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

ideally I would like to have a list of spawn positions and then a list of sprites that would spawn at those positions.

Answer (score 0):

`Sprite` is just a representation of the image to be displayed. To spawn it as an object in your scene, you need a `GameObject` with a `SpriteRenderer` or UI `Image` component attached, which then references that `Sprite` and handles getting it drawn to the screen at that location.

You can set up a `GameObject` in your scene that looks the way you want your card to look, then drag that object from your Scene Hierarchy tab into one of your Project tab's Asset folders to save it as a "prefab". Then you can spawn instances of that prefab and override their sprite if needed, like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CardSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Don't pluralize variables that refer to a single item.    
    public Transform spawnPoint;

    // Assign this prefab reference in the inspector.
    // Here I'm assuming you want a SpriteRenderer, not a UI Image.
    public SpriteRenderer cardPrefab;

    public Sprite cardSprite;

    void Start()
    {
        Spawncard();
    }

    public void Spawncard()
    {
        // Spawn a copy of the card prefab at your desired location/orientation.
        SpriteRenderer instance = Instantiate(
                                    cardPrefab, 
                                    spawnPoint.transform.position, 
                                    Quaternion.identity
                                  );

        // Set the sprite on the card to the one you want to display.
        // Note that this means you can re-use the same card prefab
        // for many different sprites.
        instance.sprite = cardSprite;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how do i utilise multiple spawn points

Comment: Probably using an array or list. The details from there depend on what you want to do with those multiple spawn points.

Comment: if i have a bunch of sprites how can i easily convert them to gameobjects

Comment: You don't convert them. You follow the instructions above: add one new GameObject to your scene. Add a SpriteRenderer component to it. Adjust the settings so the card looks the way you want in your game view. Then drag that one GameObject into your Assets folder to make it a prefab. Now you can use this prefab with the script above to display any of your card sprites.